# Is $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus S^{n-1}$ path connected?

Tags: general-topology

Is $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus S^{n-1}$ path connected? I don't know if I understood the question correctly. Is $S^{n-1}$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$? If so, then the answer would be no, for example $n=2$ and then it's trivial to show that the mean value theorem doesn't hold.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $S^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere in $R^n$.

Comment: I edited this in for you, but you should post the actual question in the body of your message (you only had it in the title).

Comment: Is it $\mathbb{R}^n/S^{n-1}$, or $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus S^{n-1}$? The former sounds more like topology than calculus, and the answer is different for the two.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{R}^n / S^{n-1}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus S^{n-1}$? In the first case, the answer is "yes". In the second case, the ansewer is "no".

Comment: My mistake. I should've written $R^n ∖ S^{n-1}$. Would my example not work? Is the unit sphere $S^1$ just the point $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you join a point with norm $<1$ to a point with norm $>1$ with a path $\gamma$ with $\vert \gamma\vert \neq 1$?

Comment: But wouldn't that first point not be part of the space in the question?

Comment: ? In $\mathbb{R}^n - \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, you pick two points $x$ and $y$, and try to join them with a path. If $x$ and $y$ are of norm >1, no problem. Same if their norm are <1. But if one is >1 and the other <1, your path need to cross the sphere...

Comment: Thanks for this, it makes sense. Does $R^n ∖S^{n−1}$ imply $R^n - S^{n-1}$?

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Would that not mean: "All the points of $R^n$ that aren't in the unit sphere"?

Comment: Sorry I just realized my mistake. I thought sphere = ball. My bad! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep, both of them... The standard notation is yours, but i did not find the latex code :D

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}^n - S^{n-1}$ is not path connected since it is not connected (path connectedness implies connectedness) since the open unit ball $B$ = {$x \in \mathbb{R}^n\space\vert\space \|x\| < 1$} and $\mathbb{R}^n - (S^{n-1}\cup B)$ form a separation of $\mathbb{R}^n - S^{n-1}$.